# Upload files from local directory to SFTP using Ruby

Tags: ruby

For some reason SFTP upload in Ruby (copy files from local directory to SFTP server) doesn't seem to work. I'm currently using Ruby 2.5.3. I would really appreciate any ideas :

My code below:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/sftp'

server = 'sftp.secure.net'
username = '123456'
password = "Mypassword*"
uid = '123456'

files = Dir.entries(outdir)
Net::SFTP.start(server, username, :password=>password) do |sftp|
  for filename in files
     #puts files
      puts "Browsing files..." 
      puts "File: #{filename}" 
     #puts new_filename

####### replacing , for | ########

     if /#{uid}_test_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{8}.txt$/ =~ filename
     file = "#{outdir}\\#{filename}"
     puts "SFTPing #{file}"
     sftp.upload(file) 
     puts "SFTP Complete for file #{file}"
     puts "Cleanup"
     puts "Deleting #{file}."
     File.delete(file)
     puts "Files were deleted." 
     end
  end
puts "Closing SFTP connection..." 
sftp.close
puts "SFTP connection closed."
end
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without knowing what gem you're using, and what error you're getting.
But assuming you're using https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp/tree/master/lib/net/sftp
it looks like `upload` is not a defined function, and you'll need to use `upload!`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Kennycoc!  That upload! was definitely helpful.  Also, sftp.close() should be deleted for sftp.  The SFTP connection automatically close. This is needed for FTP I found out, but not for SFTP.

Thanks!

Finalized Version:

```
files = Dir.entries(outdir)
Net::SFTP.start(hostname, username, :password=>password) do |sftp|
for filename in files
     #puts files
      puts "Browsing files..." 
      puts "File: #{filename}" 
     #puts new_filename

####### replacing , for | ########

     if /#{uid}_test_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{8}.txt$/ =~ filename
     file = "#{outdir}\\#{filename}"
     puts "SFTPing #{file}"
     sftp.upload!(file) 
     puts "SFTP Complete for file #{file}"
     puts "Cleanup"
     puts "Deleting #{file}."
     File.delete(file)
     puts "Files were deleted." 
     end
end
#puts "Closing SFTP connection..." 
#sftp.close()
puts "SFTP connection closed."
end
```

Answer (score 1):

SFTP is an entirely different protocol based on the network protocol SSH (Secure Shell).

Read [SFTP vs. FTPS: The Key Differences](https://www.goanywhere.com/blog/2016/11/23/sftp-vs-ftps-the-key-differences)
.

Use gem [net-sftp](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp).

**Ex:**

```
require "net/sftp"

Net::SFTP.start("host", "username", :password: "password") do |sftp|
    #from your system(local)
    sftp.upload!("/path/to/local", "/path/to/remote")
    
    # through URL
    open(your_file_url) do |file_data|
        sftp.upload!(file_data, /path/to/remote)
    end
end
```